# Is there any way to use an annotation's value in another annotation?

Tags: java, annotations

I have several runtime annotations in my codes and have some duplicated value for some of them, for example:

```
@A(value="/get")
@B(value="/get")
@C(value="/get")
public void methodA(){}
```

Is there any way that I can use predefined annotation's value? such as:

```
@A(value="/get")
@B(value=A.value)
@C(value=A.value)
public void methodA(){}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [specification requires that Annotation values be compile-time constants](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/annotations.html), so you cannot reference another annotation's value at compile time, but they can all share the same compile-time constant:

```
private static final String COMMON = "/get";

@A(value=COMMON)
@B(value=COMMON)
@C(value=COMMON)
public void methodA() { /* ... */ }
```